# Change delimiter in not regular CSV

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have the following CSV file:

```
ID,COUNTRY,DESCRIPTION,PRICE
1,USA,Short description,11
2,UK,"Description with comma , inside",2.3
```

So if field contains comma, it is put in double quotes.

How to replace delimiter from comma to tabulator but ignore commas in quotes? So I will have:

```
ID    COUNTRY    DESCRIPTION    PRICE
1    USA    Short description    11
2    UK    "Description with comma , inside"    2.3
```

or without double quotes:

```
ID    COUNTRY    DESCRIPTION    PRICE
1    USA    Short description    11
2    UK    Description with comma , inside    2.3
```

I use this code before I noticed that some fields contain commas:

```
$VAR='\t'
sed -i $"s/,/$VAR/" $FILE_NAME
```

Comment: On So its highly encouraged to add efforts in questions. So kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then.

Comment: it was mistake, edited

Comment: Look into `csvkit` tools.

Comment: Don't you need to convert tabs in your data to blanks or something else so you don't end up with more fields than you started with? See also [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^",]*"[^"]*)*"[^"]*),/\1\n/;ta;y/,/\t/;y/\n/,/' file
```

Convert all commas inside double quotes to newlines, convert remaining commas to tabs (or whatever) and then convert newlines back to commas.

N.B. This will not work if the new delimiter is a newline or if there are quoted double quotes inside double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `awk`, could you please try following written with shown samples(In case you want to make edit within Input_file itself then append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` in following solutions too).

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS="\t" '{$1=$1}1' Input_file
```

OR to remove `"` from starting and ending of the fields of line then run following.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS="\t" '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i)
  }
  $1=$1
}
1
' Input_file
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, that FPAT looks to be exactly what I needed...unfortunately it does not work in our system,  because we have lower awk installed (< 4.0)

Comment: @user1632454, sure no issues cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @user1632454 you should update your gawk version as you're about 10 years out of date and missing a few bug fixes and a ton of extremely useful new functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has a nice [csv module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html):

```sh
ruby -rcsv -e '
  out = CSV.new($stdout, col_sep: "\t")
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| out << row}
' file.csv
```

Will automatically quote output fields with tabs:

```sh
$ cat -A file.csv
ID,COUNTRY,DESCRIPTION,PRICE$
1,USA,Short description,11$
2,UK,"Description with comma , inside",2.3$
3,CA,"Description with^Itab inside",2.3$

$ ruby -rcsv -e '
  out = CSV.new($stdout, col_sep: "\t")
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| out << row}
' file.csv
ID  COUNTRY DESCRIPTION PRICE
1   USA Short description   11
2   UK  Description with comma , inside 2.3
3   CA  "Description with   tab inside" 2.3
```